# How execute method from array with different classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 2 class:

1. Class T1 with field ID.
2. Class T2, which inherited from T1
   class T2 have unique field SomeProperty.

Also I have unique property and array, that contains both of type objects (T1 and T2). I need get ID by this property, but I dunno how it realise correctly.

```
public class T_One
{
    protected int id;
    public T_One(int foo)
    {
        id = foo;
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
    }
}
public class T_Two : T_One
{
    protected int someProperty;
    public T_Two(int id, int foo) : base(id)
    {
        someProperty = foo;
    }
    public int Property
    {
        get { return someProperty; }
    }
}
//I have some solution, but I think it's BAD idea with try-catch.
public int GetObjectIDByProperty(Array Objects, int property)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Objects.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (((T_Two)(Objects.GetValue(i))).Property == property)
                {
                    return ((T_Two)Objects.GetValue(i)).ID;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //cause object T_one don't cast to object T_Two
            }
        }
    return -1; //Object with this property didn't exist
}
```

Comment: Code, show us your code first

Comment: Maybe you could provide some examples as a code. I can't get grips of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Without some code, there's only one answer we can give you: `M-m-m-magic!`

Comment: What is your array a type of? if its object you can cast `T1`, but you should have an array of `T1` then its as simple as you would hope it'd be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Access the method by casting.

Do check the type with `is` Operator beforehand. Followed by the cast to prevent using the try/catch block and you could also use foreach instead of `for` to make the code simpler:

```
    public int GetObjectIDByProperty(Array Objects, int property)
    {
        foreach(T_One myT_One in Objects)
        { 
            //Check Type with 'is'
            if (myT_One is T_Two))
            {
                //Now cast:
                T_Two myT_Two = (T_Two)myT_One;    

                if (myT_Two.Property == property)
                    return myT_Two.ID;
            }
        }

        return -1; //Object with this property didn't exist
    }
```

Comment: You're welcome - just a small remark: in fact you should also check the type of the objects in the Array before casting them on T_One because you have no runtime guarantee that all of them are of type T_One. You might get exceptions when you extend your list with objects that do not inherit from T_One